# Mechanical Keyboard PCB: Single Row Failure

Tags: pcb, keyboard

I’ve got a weird issue on my hands and could use some advice. I built a mechanical keyboard and it worked for about a week, before the number row stopped working (no liquid damage or vibration/physical damage). I have a multimeter, but little experience in using it, so I probably haven’t been as through as I could. Anyway, here is what I’ve tried:

- I’ve checked that the entire top row is connected to each other.
- I have shorted ground to hot on a single key and it typed the entire column on the keyboard.
- I’ve found a pin on the microcontroller that is connected to the top row, but not the other rows, and it seems to be correctly soldered to the board.
- I’ve re-flashed the firmware to default.
- I’ve tried different computers, and cables.

I had previously been cautious of the integrity of the micro-USB connector, but don’t know how to verify that its ok with the multimeter. Even if the board is just ‘dead’, I’d still appreciate knowing what some of the potential issues were. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a photo of the board:[image]

And a close up of the microcontroller: [image]

And a close up of the top right of the board: [image]

Comment: If most keys on the keyboard work correctly, then the USB portion must be working.

Comment: Spend some time understanding how this actually works.  Possibly write a temporary, alternate firmware for the MCU to test various possibilities of what might be wrong.  Repair of consumer products questions are off topic here, to qualify as on topic you must approach the problem from an actual *understanding* of how the circuit is supposed to operate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I understand the basics, the row-column ID scheme and the key switches completing the circuit, and I know the keyboard doesn’t work but I don’t know what part of this PCB could fail in such a way that causes the observed behavior, hence my question. I’d say the question is about understanding.

Comment: So write some new firmwares that test various possibilities or aid probing those possibilities.  For example excite whichever side of the matrix is driven, on that line only.  In terms of this site, it's quite problematic that you're asking about something clearly designed as some sort of kit (it appears to effectively be an overgrown Arduino Leonardo) but aren't providing any of the engineering documentation of it.  That makes it an off-topic consumer product question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton There isn’t any engineering documentation, but that aside, I was looking for advice on the possible failure of the hardware, its ok if you can’t provide that.

Comment: It's a question of the rules of this site: we don't do product repair advice, we do engineering problem solving.  I've already suggested a method, for understanding the failure by developing an understanding of the proper operation, but you don't particularly seem interested in pursuing it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Repair is likely not possible in this case. I want to figure out what went wrong. How would rewriting the firmware help me find the hardware failure?

Comment: On the contrary, repair is certainly possible and likely fairly simple as this has "hobby project" written all over it in terms of parts choices which are nothing like typical manufactured keyboards.   Writing a custom firmware would allow you to excite just one part of the circuit at a time and see if it is functioning in the way you expect.  These firmware wouldn't actually be keyboards, they'd just drive an I/O or two and perhaps monitor some others.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the hell of it, i'd swap Q1 &  Q2 to see if the fault moves down a row... but then again, i'm not a coder, i'm a tinkerer.  it looks like a scanning method of registering keystrokes (i can't read the chip numbers) and i'd personally start looking at Q1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just a hobbyist myself.
I was browsing over the board and I noticed the screw (shown in image).
This screw location is extremely questionable to me.
It seems like it creates a place of contact with the that trace. (Of course this isn't the top row.)
I mention this because long ago building 386 computers we'd place the mainboards in cases and at times the mainboards would have designs like this and they'd hit the metal stand-offs and the computer would intermittently reboot.

The point is, is it possible you secured the board more after completing assembly and you changed something that way. (It sounds like you did some work to put things together) Take the board out of this case and try and see if it works without all those fasteners (please attend to all safety precautions).  You may be surprised.

[image: top portion of board]